# For log z = ln|z| + i θ where pi/4 < θ < 9pi/4 find the domain of analyticity (in terms of angle theta) in complex plane.

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, complex-numbers, logarithms, analyticity

State the forbidden and allowed paths.
I understand that log function is not differentiable along negative axis and 0 but how do I found the domain angle? And what is meant by forbidden and allowed paths?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Denote by $\Omega$ the complex plane with the $45^\circ$ ray $\{t(1+i)\,|\,t\geq0\}$ removed. The function
$$\theta(z):={\rm arg}(z)\>\cap\ ]\pi/4,\>9\pi/4[\>$$
is a well defined and continuous real-valued function on $\Omega$. It follows that 
$$f(z):=\log|z|+i\theta(z)\ .$$
is a well defined and continuous complex-valued function on $\Omega$. Checking the CR equations shows that $f$ is in fact analytic in $\Omega$, and one finds that
$$f'(z)={1\over z}\qquad(z\in\Omega)\ .$$
What is the relation between this $f$ and the principal value  of the logarithm, denoted by ${\rm Log}\>$? The latter is defined in the domain $\Omega_*\>$, obtained by making a slit along the negative real axis. Since both $f$ and ${\rm Log}$ have the same derivative $z\mapsto{1\over z}$ the difference between these two functions is locally constant. **But:** The constant may be different in different components of $\Omega\cap\Omega_*$. I suggest you draw a figure and find out what exactly is happening in this example.

There is no such thing as "forbidden" or "allowed" path, unless further context is established.

Comment: Ok, so it is written that allowed path is the one which you can  move along in quadrants to reach the given function  by only crossing analytic parts, excluding branch cut. And forbidden path is opposite.